# Is the order of inserts specified for INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-select

I have a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE {
  email VARCHAR PRIMARY,
  last_login DATE
}
```

And I can populate with a select result set like:

```
("a@b.c", "2019-01-01"),
("a@b.c", "2019-02-01")
```

If I will insert into that table using `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT`, is it specified which row gets inserted and which is ignored?

Found specification:

- "Specify IGNORE to ignore rows that would cause duplicate-key violations." from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html. But this does not say which is the duplicate and which is the not-duplicate.

Comment: The fact that it's "flagged as unsafe for statement-based replication" suggests that it might be not deterministic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert` statement doesn't specify the order the rows are inserted - the `select` statement does. However, unless you explicitly define the order with an `order by` clause, the order `select` returns rows is completely up to the database, and shouldn't be trusted.

In other words, if you care which row gets inserted and which gets ignored, add an `order by` clause to your `select` statement and make sure that the row you want to insert comes first.

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, I am using an `ORDER BY` on the `... SELECT` part. But I was not sure if the select ordering was specified to be processed "in order" by the insert part.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken the docs don't state so explicitly, but they do state using insert-select without an `order by` clause is non-deterministic, and thus recommend that you use an `order by` (see the last three paragraphs in the doc you linked). From here, you can infer that the behavior **with** an `order by` clause is deterministic.