# Is it specified that INSERT IGNORE... SELECT is performed in order?

Tags: sql, duplicates, mariadb, sql-order-by, sql-insert

The MariaDB `INSERT IGNORE... SELECT` syntax is defined at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/.

I am also relying on the assumption that each `INSERT` in this situation will be performed in the order of the `SELECT` clause result set.

Test case:

```sql
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS index_and_color;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE index_and_color (`index` INT PRIMARY KEY, color TEXT);
INSERT IGNORE INTO index_and_color SELECT 5, "Red" UNION ALL SELECT 5, "Blue";
SELECT * FROM index_and_color;
```

Intuitively, I see that the "first" row in the `SELECT` clause result set has `(5, "Red")` and then the "second" row is ignored, containing the same key with "Blue".

From what I see, this is undefined behavior because another server implementing the same documentation could handle the rows in a different order.

**Is my usage here indeed relying on undefined behavior?**

Comment: I have asked this same question regarding MySQL at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841179/is-the-order-of-inserts-specified-for-insert-ignore-select. And strictly speaking, it is undefined behavior there.

Answer (score 1):

What is "undefined behavior" is the ordering of the rows returned by an `UNION ALL` query. Use an `ORDER BY` clause if you want a stable result:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO index_and_color (`index`, color)
SELECT 5 `index`, 'Red' color UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Blue' ORDER BY color;
```

Comment: I understand that the result set can be ordered by color. But nowhere in the INSERT documentation does it say "the first result of the result set will be inserted first".

Comment: This means it would be perfectly acceptable for the implementation to do "a random row from the result set will be inserted, continuing until all results are inserted"

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement `SELECT * FROM index_and_color` should give you exactly for what you asked: all data rows from the given table.

If you expect that the resultset will be delivered in a specific order, then you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause, otherwise it might be ordered by index, or based on whichever algorithm the optimizer expects to produce the data the fastest.

For example::

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a int, b int, index(a));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2,1),(1,2);

/* Here we get the order from last insert statement */
SELECT a,b FROM t1;
MariaDB [test]> select a,b from t1;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+

/* Here we get the another order since the optimizer will deliver results from index */
SELECT a FROM t1;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
```